# Filter "widget_comments_args" won't work

Tags: widgets

I used "widget_comments_args" for changing comments query for Recent Comments, but it won't work.

```
add_filter( 'widget_comments_args', 'my_function_name' );
function my_function_name( $comment_args ) {
    $comment_args['post_type'] = 'post';
    $comment_args['type'] = 'comment';
    return $comment_args;
}
```

Comment: What output you were expecting? What did you get? I tested with the filter in your code and its working fine.

Comment: I expected recent comments widgets doesn't show other post types comments, But it's still showing.